# OpenGL check if something is enabled or disabled

Tags: c++, opengl

is there any function like `isEnabled(GL_LIGHTING);` or any way to detect if is something enabled or disabled?

Comment: Really, have you just tried your initial guess (after transformaing it into GL-style, like say `glIsEnabled`) at all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For global lighting, how about:

```
glIsEnabled(GL_LIGHTING)
```

Answer (score 11):

[glGet](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGet) — return the value or values of a selected parameter.

```
glGetBooleanv(GL_LIGHTING,&status)
```